# Using Perl to read list and format to a customized output file

Tags: perl

I have a file with a list, call it `tbl.lst`:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I want to create an output file with the items enclosed in parentheses and separated by commas. Can someone show me how to do this in Perl?

Expected output:

```
MYTABLES=(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Stack Overflow is not a "please write my code for me" service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -lne 'push @A, $_; END { print "MYTABLES=(", join(",", @A), ")";}' tbl.lst
```

Given the input file `tbl.lst`:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

The output is:

```
MYTABLES=(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Every space in the Perl script is optional (but it is probably clearer for the spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This script will work as a filter: reads the file and prints the result to stdout like this:

```
./script file
```

Here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    s/\r|\n//g;  # On any platform, strip linefeeds on any (other) platform
    push @items, $_
}
print "MYTABLES=(";
while (@items) {
    $item = shift @items;
    print $item;
    print @items ? "," : ")\n";
}
```

If the input file gets really big, you might want to avoid reading it into a list and, instead, work strictly line by line. Then the trick is to print the separators before the items.

```
print "MYTABLES=";
while (<>) {
    print $first_printed ? "," : "(";
    s/\r|\n//g;  # On any platform, strip linefeeds on any (other) platform
    print;
    $first_printed = 1; 
}
print ")\n";
```

Comment: This is overly complicated, and optimizes for weird cases (aka. `\r\n` line endings on Unix – this should be tackled by `dos2unix` (or `:crlf` PerlIO layer) and `chomp`).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR!=1{a=a","}{a=a$0}END{print "MYTABLES=("substr(a,0,length(a))")"}' your_file >output.txt
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
a
b
c
d
e
> awk 'NR!=1{a=a","}{a=a$0}END{print "MYTABLES=("substr(a,0,length(a))")"}' temp
MYTABLES=(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Comment: What happened to `e`?  And what happened to `perl`?  :D

Comment: Your perl is already a good one..so thought i would give an awk and yes.. e now is there